# How do I use Select2 in a BigCommerce Stencil theme

Tags: npm, jquery-select2, bigcommerce

I would like to use the jQuery select2 library on my Stencil theme for my BigCommerce store. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this on the Cornerstone theme, you'll follow these steps.

1. Add Select2 to your package.json `npm install select2 --save`
2. Add Select2 to your webpack config resolve/alias `select2: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js'),`
3. Import library where you wish to use it(e.g. product.js) `import 'select2';`
4. Import Select2 css `@import "../../node_modules/select2/src/scss/core";`
5. Now you'll need to call `select2()` on any fields you want it run on. I accomplished this by

   1. Create custom product template
   2. Create custom product-view template
   3. Create custom replacement for the `dynamicComponent` for product options
   4. Add `select2` class to any `select` elements you want it run on
   5. Run `$('.select2').select2();` inside product.js `onReady`
   6. Lastly, you made need to fix up the CSS in order for select2 to display properly. Try `.select2 {font-size: $input-small-fontSize;}`

Since the trickiest part of this was the custom `dynamicComponent` template, here is what I made

```
{{#if this.type "===" "Configurable_PickList_Set"}}
    {{#if this.partial "===" "set-radio"}}
        {{> components/products/options/set-radio this }}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if this.partial "===" "set-rectangle"}}
        {{> components/products/options/set-rectangle this }}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if this.partial "===" "set-select"}}
        {{> components/products/options/set-select this select2="true" }}
    {{/if}}
{{else}}
    {{{dynamicComponent 'components/products/options'}}}
{{/if}}
```